# Load image in DIV from url obtained from a TEXT BOX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying t load an image into div tag from a url which is obtained from a textbox.My current file is as follows..I don't know what else to be done

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="imageURL1">
        <div class="ImageContainer">
          image will appear here:  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure javascript you can load the image as follows. I am using the onChange event to detect whether url has been supplied to the textbox or not. On pressing Enter key, the image will be loaded in the div.

```js
function addImage()
{
  var url = document.getElementsByClassName("imageURL1")[0].value;
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  document.getElementsByClassName("ImageContainer")[0].appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" class="imageURL1" onChange="addImage();">
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      image will appear here:  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I liked this solution. Though you could use innerHTML instead of appendElement so that image will get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Submit").click(function(){
        var image_url = $(".imageURL1").val();
        $(".ImageContainer").html("<img src='"+image_url+"' width='200'>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="imageURL1">
<button id="Submit">Submit</button>
<div class="ImageContainer">
          
</div>
```

Js fiddle example -> http://jsfiddle.net/0kvxpnmv/

Comment: Accept it as accepted answer if it works for you. so that I can help other visitors :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<img src="'+image_url+'">').load(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('.ImageContainer');
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zb1fmef/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about using a button to call a funtion that'll change the image src with url in the text box

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="imageURL1">
        <button onclick="func()">Load image</button>
        <div class="ImageContainer">
          <img src="" id="imgContainer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript**

```
(function(){
var func = function(){
 var url = $(".imageURL1").val()
 $('#imgContainer').attr('src',url)
}

})();
```

Here's the jsFiddle [with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/2d7axmdr/) and [without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/2d7axmdr/2/)

Comment: $('imgCOntainer') should be $('#imgContainer')

Comment: Sorry this is not working.. should i add any jquery files??

Comment: I though you need jQuery coz you mentioned it in tags. anyways, here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d7axmdr/2/) without jQuery :)

Comment: can i do this without image container??

Comment: What do you mean by "image container" ? The class of `<div>` that surrounds the `<img>` tag or the id of `<img>` tag itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `php`

```
index.php file
<form action="GetURL.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="url">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now when they click submit it will take you to the new page

```
GetURL.php

$image_url = $_REQUEST['url'];

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="imageURL1">
        <div class="ImageContainer">
          <?php echo '<img src="{$image}"/>'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On this page you can see that in your `imageContainer class` you have the image url being posted with `PHP`

The best way to handle this from here would be to have the form on the same page as the image and have it post the url with ajax.

So you would type in the url to the textbox and when your done it refreshes the image url.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my code below, on the change event of the text input, it would create an jQuery img tag then add then use the URL from the input as the source and clear the contents of the output div. Once the image is loaded, it will replace the content of the output div.

```
$('.imageURL1').change(function() {
    var $img = $('<img/>');
    $img.attr('src', $(this).val());
    $img.load(function() {
        $('.ImageContainer').html(this);
    });
});
```

This solution requires jQuery.

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8sn5rmu6/1/).

Comment: I tried that but the image is not appearing...Need any jquery files to add with it??

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I assumed you were using jQuery already since you have the jQuery tag.